# Not able to set autocommit value to false in Oracle Data Source connection

Tags: java, spring, oracle

Inserting values in Oracle 11g via JdbcTemplate-OracleDataSource injected via Spring config file. Transactions are done via @Transactional managed by DataSourceTransactionManager.

Question 1) is how to set the autocommit value to false through the Spring config file.
Tried with :

```
    <property name="autoCommit" value="false" />

    <property name="defaultAutoCommit" value="false" />
```

Both are giving error:
 org.springframework.beans.NotWritablePropertyException: Invalid property 'defaultAutoCommit' of bean class [oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleDataSource]

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

These properties won't work because there is no `setAutoCommit()` or `setDefaultAutoCommit()` methods in [OracleDataSource](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18283_01/appdev.112/e13995/oracle/jdbc/pool/OracleDataSource.html).

What there is there and we can use instead is [OracleDataSource#setConnectionProperties()](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18283_01/appdev.112/e13995/oracle/jdbc/pool/OracleDataSource.html#setConnectionProperties_java_util_Properties_) that is has Properties as argument and we can define on the fly in the OracleDataSource Spring bean by adding property:

```
<property name="connectionProperties">
   <props merge="default">
      <prop key="AutoCommit">false</prop>
   </props>
</property>
```